# Find client's remote hostname and portnumber

Tags: java, client-server, portforwarding, file-sharing

Developing a p2p application where in I want to transfer files to a client whosoever's portnumber is open.

For example, if the server has port number 200 and 2 clients have port numbers: 300 and 400 then

- how can I grab clients IP addr
- how do I detect if client port numbers are open
- how do I configure the server client setup (believe I can achieve this via port forwarding but not sure)

Comment: You can't, in CORBA. Why CORBA? These things are usually built with UDP I believe.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475644/identify-client-in-peer-to-peer-filesharing-using-java-and-corba-and-build-sock/25480509#25480509

Comment: Dont want corba and the question you linked did not answer my above 3 questions even when I looked more into it